# python sorted function does not seem to work on windows

Tags: python, sorting

I am sorting a csv file using python 3 with the following code. It works perfectly on MAC but on Windows(either real or Fusion) I get this exception. Anyone seen this or have a suggestion?

```
Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
File "Z:\bin\FDTSEfiles\HrsWonVal.py", line 470, in <lambda>
    Button(newOrExisting, text="OK", command=lambda: getnewOrExisting_File(U_cmd.get())).grid(row=5, column=1)
File "Z:\bin\FDTSEfiles\HrsWonVal.py", line 466, in getnewOrExisting_File
    reverseOrderAndFilterFile(existingFilePath)
File "Z:\bin\FDTSEfiles\HrsWonVal.py", line 510, in reverseOrderAndFilterFile
    sortedlist = sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(3))

# 3 specifies the 4th column - Date IndexError: list index out of range
```

My code:

```
data = csv.reader(open(reverseAndFilteredPathFileName),delimiter=',')
sortedlist = sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(3))   
with open(reverseAndFilteredPathFileName, "w") as f:
    fileWriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in sortedlist:
        fileWriter.writerow(row)
f.close()
```

Comment: What does your CSV look like? It looks like you're trying to access a column that doesn't exist.

Comment: Pass `newline=''` to `open()` for csv files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Footnotes in the `csv` module [docs](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/csv.html#id3):

> If `newline=''` is not specified, newlines embedded
>   inside quoted fields will not be interpreted correctly, and on
>   platforms that use `\r\n` linendings on write an extra `\r` will be added.
>   It should always be safe to specify `newline=''`, since the csv module
>   does its own (universal) newline handling.

Windows happens to be a (...the) platform that uses `\r\n` for line endings.  That is why you are getting platform-specific behavior; get rid of it by specifying `newline=''` to `open`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
Tried with newline='' but no luck. 
data = csv.reader(open(reverseAndFilteredPathFileName, newline=''),delimiter=',', quotechar='"'). 
The data file contains the right number of columns. It works perfectly on MAC.

Comment: Then use your own key function in place of itemgetter to diagnose why you are getting an IndexError.

Comment: While you're writing your own key function, print out the values so you know what line in your CSV file is causing the problem. That might give you a better idea if it's extra newlines or too few columns.

Comment: Finally found the problem and it is as you said - newline='' just took me a while to actually find the offending open. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`sorted`works fine whatever the platform. The traceback tells you exactly where the error happens, and obviously it has to do with your data not being what (or not being interpreted by the csv module as) you think they should be - either the delimiter is wrong or your source file has less than four columns.